# Why does display:none not work here?

Tags: html, css

I think the problem is that #header img does not work.

```css
#header img 
{
    border-style: solid;
         border-color: #000000;
         border-width: 5px;
         padding: 5px
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 840px) { #header img { display:none; } }
```

```html
<h1><a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/platzhalter.jpg" </a></h1>
```

Comment: First try closing the first rule with `padding: 5px;` (you're missing a `;`)

Comment: Also, you aren't closing the `img` element's tag, and there is no `#header` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#header img 
{
    border-style: solid;
         border-color: #000000;
         border-width: 5px;
         padding: 5px
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 840px) { #header img { display:none; } }
```

```html
<h1><a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="images/platzhalter.jpg" </a></h1>
```

You don't have #header img, try to change #header with #logo

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 840px) { #logo img { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean **#logo** instead of **#header**? You're also missing a trailing semi-colon at the end of **padding: 5px**.

This works for me:

```
#logo img 
{
    border-style: solid;
         border-color: #000000;
         border-width: 5px;
         padding: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 840px) { #logo img { display:none; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector `#header img` does not match any element in the code snippet, since there is no element with the `id` attribute value `header`.